# Laravel - Select relation columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to write a query which selects columns from a model then selects one column from a relationship table.

**Team Model**

```
   public function members(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Membership', 'team_id', 'id', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

**Member(user) model**

```
public function skills()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Skill');
}
```

**Function**

Query i have attempted but had no luck:

```
 $members = $this->team->members()
        ->select('id', 'name')
        ->with(['skills' => function ($query) {
          $query->select('name');
        }])
        ->get();
```

**dump of query**

When i dump the query it returns just the data for the `id` and `name` columns from the team table but the skills relation returns back empty when i want it to return the name from that table.

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
    "skills" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1657 ▼
      #items: []
    }
  ]
```

How would do i grab the `name` column from the `skills` relation table within this query?

Answer (score 2):

To select column in relation you can use this :

```
->with('members.skills:id,name')
```

If you're not passing id attribute inside the with, the relation can't work

Comment: I just attemped your answer and got `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: @Lowtiercoder I just've change my answer, take a look

Comment: Call to undefined relationship [members] on model [App\User].

Comment: my team model contains the `members` hasmanythrough relation but the user model doesnt have a relation called `members`

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, $this is for what Model ? User Model ? if it's that, can you try ->with('team.members.skills:id,name') . i'm not sure for the team relation name because you didn't show you're user model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `id` to the fields returned from the `skills` table. Otherwise Eloquent has no way to link the skill to the correct team.

```
->with(['skills' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'name');
}])
```

Comment: I just attempted your answer and got. `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: Try using `skills.id` instead.

Comment: it doesn't error out now but the skills relationship returns empty as soon as i add the select for the team columns above the with statement

Comment: You need to select the `teams.id` column as well to match the records.